# Are there any short term gymnasia in Tokyo?

Tags: tokyo, sport

I'm planning to go to Japan from December to January and wondering if there are any gyms I could attend to during my stay.

I am not a Japanse citizen, nor do I have an official address there. I can speak Japanese though.

The best would be a membership that allows me to go there any time during that period, but even something like an X times pass would be acceptable.

I don't need much equipment, a squat rack and a set of free weights are enough.

Comment: Are you staying in a hotel, air bnb, friend's house?  What city is also important.

Comment: I'm doing a homestay about 10 minutes walk away from Skytree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there are, for example [Tokyo Metropolitan Gymnasium](http://www.tef.or.jp/tmg/). One time entry is ¥600 and it has the facilities you seek (and more).

Comment: Most (all?) wards in Tokyo operate public gyms open to all.

Answer (score 0):

Near Sky Tree, the Sumida-ku gymnasium looks like it may meet your requirements. Here's the access link in English.

http://www.sumidacity-gym.com/lang/honyaku_english/access_e.html

And here's the training room (Japanese). http://www.sumidacity-gym.com/sp/facility/2f_2.php#floor-2f-2-02